# How do i allow someone to connect to a website that needs client authentication cert without the cert but through a vm that has the cert?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, certificate, redirect

So here is my scenario:
There is a website that needs a cert for client authentication, unfortunately we cannot provide that cert to everyone. Also, protecting the website with the cert is not something we can change.
More details if above statements are somewhat confusing:

1. Website X (Not developed by me) needs a client authentication cert to authenticate
2. I can have the cert installed on a VM which only i have permissions to login to.
3. I want others to access Website X but cant provide the cert to them

Is there a feasible way to do this?

Here is what i think might work but not sure how to do and even if thats possible:

1. Host a website (Website Y) on the server VM
2. When someone opens that website : The ASP.Net code reads the cert calls into the Website X
3. Present the cert for client authentication to website X
4. Gets the response
5. Shows the response as it is to the user?

But the problem with this approach is the website might just return the raw html and may have its own custom code doing something when people selects a drop down or something?How do i address that?

Anyone has an idea on how i can achieve this?
My Apologies if i am not clear or if i shouldn't be asking such questions on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reverse proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org/) to solve this issue. Run nginx on your server VM and listen for connections on port 80. On the upstream side, use [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to connect to 'website X'. Present the certificate as part of the SSL handshake to perform certificate validation. Once the validation is complete, the rest of session will proceed normally.

With this approach, you shouldn't have to worry about 'website X' changing, since nginx will simply proxy all the responses back to the client.